# How to Convert a string to lua code to read value from nested table

Tags: lua-table, lua-5.3

I have a configurable value of a table fetch function which i get as an input string. I need that string to be executed as a code and fetch a value from the nested table.

I tried using `load(string)`, its not working

```
local function main()
  local t = {
    ["name1"] = "value1",
    ["name2"] = {["name1"] = "value1",
      ["name2"] = { 1, false, true, 23.54, "a \021 string" },
      name3 = nil
    },
    name3 = nil
  }
  local string = 't.name2.name1'
  print(type(string))
  print(load(string))
end
```

`print(load(string))` should print `value1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code works

```
local function main()

  t = {
    ["name1"] = "value1",
    ["name2"] = {["name1"] = "value1",
      ["name2"] = { 1, false, true, 23.54, "a \021 string" },
      name3 = nil
    },
    name3 = nil
  }
  string = "t.name2.name1"
  print(type(string))
  val = load("return "..string)()
  print(val)
end
```